# How to avoid repeating dependency versions in a multi-module Gradle project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

There's a sample Spring Boot project [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) that contains two modules.

The `build.gradle` for one of the modules looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext { springBootVersion = '2.1.4.RELEASE' }
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-multi-module-application'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile project(':library')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

The other module's `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

plugins { id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE" }

ext { springBootVersion = '2.1.4.RELEASE' }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-multi-module-library'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}") }
}
```

The `springBootVersion = '2.1.4.RELEASE'` is declared in both modules. For a 2 module project that might not be a problem, but if my project had 10 modules and I wanted to make sure that all modules always depend on the same version of Spring Boot, it would be inconvenient and error-prone to repeat this version in every module.

Similarly, I might want to add a dependency on `commons-io` to both of these modules, and ensure they both always depend on the same version of `commons-io`.

How can I avoid repeating the version numbers in each and every `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:cross_project_configuration) : a good practice in Gradle is to configure subprojects which share common traits in a single place, for example in the `root project`'s build script (or using custom plugins)

**EDIT** the solution proposed here is no longer considered as good practice from Gradle team (the link above does not even mention `subproject` bloc in latests Gradle version doc);  thank you @buggy for the warning .

In your example taken from Spring boot documentation, this pattern could be applied to centralize Spring boot and other common dependencies versions in a single place, but you could go further and also configure other common traits (Java plugin configuration, repositoties, etc..)

Here is how I would re-write the Spring example to make it cleaner and DRY:

**Root project**

```
/**
 * Add Springboot plugin into build script classpath (without applying it)
 * This is this only place where you need to define the Springboot version.
 *
 * See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation
 */
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.4.RELEASE" apply false
}

// Set version for dependencies share between subprojects
ext {
    commonsIoVersion = "2.6"
}

subprojects {
    // common config for all Java subprojects
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral() 
    }
    
    // apply Spring Boot's dependency management plugin
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
}
```

**Library sub-project**

```
// no need for additional plugins

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-multi-module-library'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}"

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES 
    }
}
```

**Application sub-project**

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot"
}

bootJar { 
    baseName = 'gs-multi-module-application'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    implementation  project(':library')

    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}"

    // could also be configured in root project.
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**Notes**

- this solution uses the new `plugins {}` DSL only (no need for old `buildscript` block)
- version of the `io.spring.dependency-management` should not be configured explicitly, it will be inherit from Spring boot plugin

Comment: Just a note about the current state: this approach is not recommended by gradle, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration

Comment: yes you're rigtht, @buggy . i've aded a note in the answer

Comment: Instead of ext block, recommended approach is gradle version catalog to declare dependency version. The best way to use  gradle version catalog is through `libs.versions.toml`  file. Only non-transitive dependency should added in version catalog.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `ext{}` block to a new file and reference it in your project's `build.gradle` file via the `apply from:` statement.

```
// project/versions.gradle
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.4.RELEASE'
}

// project/build.gradle
buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
}

// module/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "some.dependency:dependency:$springBootVersion"
}
```

Now you only have to define your dependency versions in one place.

Typically, a project will have a project-level `build.gradle` file in addition to module-specific `build.gradle` files. However, the repo you shared is missing the project-level build script. This is why the `ext{}` block is defined in each module's build script. This is likely not optimal, and I recommend looking at other repos to see how different developers tackled this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Gradle consistent versions plugin that will handle this:

https://github.com/palantir/gradle-consistent-versions

After you set this plugin up in the root `build.gradle` file, you will create a `versions.props` file like this, to use the example from the documentation.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.*:jackson-* = 2.9.6
com.google.guava:guava = 21.0
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp = 3.12.0
junit:junit = 4.12
org.assertj:* = 3.10.0
```

There's also a `versions.locks` file, which is auto-generated by `./gradlew --write-locks`. You can then specify version-less dependencies in your `build.gradle` files.